# How can I update an existing React object item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The update works! But? A new empty item is added. Does anyone know the solution to this? Sorry I'm inexperienced with React.

*Here are the codes and screenshots;*

to-do-list.js

```
<Button onClick={() => props.updateTask(data.id)} size="small" color="primary">Mark Completed</Button>
```

App.js

```
const handleUpdateTask = (id) => {
    setTodos((previousData =>
        [
            ...previousData,
            todos[id]["title"] = "update?"
        ]
    ))
}
```

Before clicking;
[image]

And After clicking;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you use `useState` hook? if yes, how about this:

```js
const handleUpdateTask = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.map(todo => todo.id === id ? {...todo, completed: true} : todo);
}
```

in code above, insted we acces index we utilize `id` property in each todo in todos array of object. than, we update its `completed` property. Hope this could help.

Comment: your welcome brother. keep learning! and have a blessed day

Comment: Thanks bro! Where can I find a more detailed article of this code block?

Comment: I don't know, because I really often use this code . but, if you want to deep dive into react world you could try to look at this blog https://kentcdodds.com/blog/ or this https://www.robinwieruch.de/blog